# Compute compass heading from point to point in a 2D plane

Tags: r, trigonometry

I am trying to figure out how to write a R function to compute the compass heading FROM a point in space TO a nearby stationary tower. The distances are close enough to assume a 2d plane. I played around with tan-1(m) but I don't seem to get the right answer.

I need the output in degrees and to be flexible no matter which direction the tower happens to be relative to the point (as in the point can be at any bearing from the tower).

Does anyone know how to do this? Here is some data:

```
dat <- data.frame("pointID" = c(1,2,3,4),
             "X" = c(640379,640430, 640308, 637710),
             "Y" = c(3933474,3933575, 3933365, 3935346),
             "towerX" = rep(640372,4),
             "towerY" = rep(3933487,4))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not clear to me what coordinate system is of your values. But assuming they are UTM I would convert them to WGS80 (then they are nicely plotable on google maps etc) using something like this:

```
UTMtoWGS80 <- function(x, y){
  require(rgdal)
  d <- data.frame(lat = y,
                  lon = x)
  coordinates(d) <- c("lon", "lat")
  proj4string(d) <- CRS("+init=epsg:32630")
  d <- spTransform(d,CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
  return(data.frame(d@coords))
}

pos <- UTMtoWGS80(dat$X, dat$Y)
tower <- UTMtoWGS80(dat$towerX, dat$towerY)
```

Next make a function to calculate the compass bearings, e.g.:

```
radians <- function(deg) return(deg*pi/180)

degrees <- function(x) x * (180 / pi)

bearing <- function(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2){
  lat1 <- radians(lat1) 
  lat2 <- radians(lat2)
  dLon = radians(lng2-lng1)
  y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2)
  x = cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(dLon)
  brng = degrees(atan2(y, x))
  (brng + 360) %% 360
}
```

This is basically adapted from this useful [resource](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), and produces the following bearings:

```
> bearing(pos$lat, pos$lon, tower$lat, tower$lon)
[1] 332.70347 214.17031  28.47364 125.93292
```

Clearly this is dependent on the initial assumption of UTM data.